# Google sheet formats numbers incorrectly when a .csv file is uploaded to google drive

Tags: google-sheets

I have following data in my .csv file (generated by a python script):

```
"count","spbli_sku","calendar_week"
1,"2000.100",43
2,"2000.100",45
2,"2000.100",47
2,"2000.20",41
3,"2000.20",42
7,"2000.20",43
11,"2000.20",44
15,"2000.20",45
```

When I upload this file into the google drive, google formats '2000.10' to '2000.1' and '2000.20' to '2000.2'. And even if I open this doc in google sheets I can format it back to the initial value.

What could I go to get the initial values (as I have them in the initial .csv file) in google sheet?

[image]

Comment: About `When I upload this file into the google drive, google formats '2000.10' to '2000.1' and '2000.20' to '2000.2'.`, if you are uploading the CSV data using a script, can you show your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike I don't upload it with a script. It is a manual process

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, when your CSV data is manually uploaded to Google Drive, when I saw it by the viewer, I could replicate your issue. But, when I saw it by a text editor, the uploaded CSV raw data can be seen. So in this case, when the CSV file is converted to Google Spreadsheet, it seems that the default number format is used. In your case, I think that it is required to put the values to Spreadsheet by giving the custom number format, or put the values as the string. This can be achieved by a script. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You can try editing your python script and add a single apostrophe(') before the number values that you want to retain the format when uploading to drive or google sheets. See below screenshots for the result:

**CSV file to upload:**

[image]

**How it appears in drive/sheets:**

[image]

The drive retains the format because adding apostrophe before a number in your upload file will convert the value to string thus retaining the format that you have before uploading.

Reference: [Link](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/keep-leading-zeros-in-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=Add%20Apostrophe%20(%27)%20Before%20the%20Number&text=All%20you%20need%20to%20do,zeros%20don%27t%20go%20away.)

Comment: It is a weird workaround. What if a file is not produced by python but rather extracted as csv from the db?

Comment: Agreed with @alina. I think that quote prefixing is not native to the CSV format, where you'd normally expect shell-like notions of quoting and escaping. But that's more of a compatibility quirk of google sheets -- I think this should be the accepted answer, good job @jason-e!

Answer (score 0):

You can import [these formats](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608) in a Spreadsheet. Once you do it the numbers will automatically be converted as you mentioned.

In order to show the format like **2000.10** instead of **2000.1** you should select the column or cells in question and go to the top menu, then click on **Format > Number > More formats > Custom number formats**, here you will see the different samples in order to get an idea of how to format your number. In your specific case if you mean to change 2000.1 to 2000.10 use the format **0.00** or use **0.000** if you want 2000.100 instead of 2000.10

### Reference

[Format numbers in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470)

Comment: Yes and no. Imagine I have values '2000.10' and '2000.100'. You approach will not help me with this.

Comment: Then you've got to use Google Apps Script and triggers. By default you can't import with the format you want but format your cells afterwards. To better investigate this, my question is what's the purpose to keep that format while importing?